# Create a Generic Service Factory

Tags: c#, .net, generics, service, factory

I am trying to create something like a 2 layered architecture, where the service layer instance is always required to created by the factory in the service layer. I want that service factory to be generic and return an interface. I have done something like this:

```c#
// service base interface
namespace SimpleFW.Services
{
    public interface IServiceBase
    {
        void Get();
        void Create();
        void Update();
        void Delete();
    }
}
```

below code is created to add the custom features per service:

```c#
// interface for the custom implementation
namespace SimpleFW.Services
{
    public interface ISimpleService : IServiceBase
    {
        void CustomMethod();
    }
}
```

here is how a service is implemented

```c#
// implementation of the service
namespace SimpleFW.Services
{
    public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
    {
        public void CustomMethod()
        {
            Debug.Write("CustomMethod Method Called.");
        }

        public void Get()
        {
            Debug.Write("Get Method Called.");
        }

        public void Create()
        {
            Debug.Write("Create Method Called.");
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            Debug.Write("Update Method Called.");
        }

        public void Delete()
        {
            Debug.Write("Delete Method Called.");
        }
    }
}
```

this is a generic factory which will create the instance of the service:

```c#
// service factory
namespace SimpleFW.Services
{
    public class ServiceFactory
    {
        public static IServiceBase GetService<T>() where T : IServiceBase, new()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the service client in the separate assembly

```c#
// service client in separate assembly
namespace SimpleFW.Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceBase service = ServiceFactory.GetService<SimpleService>();

            service.Get(); // should be callable from within the same assembly not from client assembly
            service.Create(); // should be callable from within the same assembly not from client assembly
            service.Update(); // should be callable from within the same assembly not from client assembly
            service.Delete(); // should be callable from within the same assembly not from client assembly

            ((ISimpleService)service).CustomMethod(); // this is fine. I should be able to cast and call the methods like this

            SimpleService serObject = new SimpleService(); // how to make this impossible
        }
    }
}
```

Though I have written the comments next to the code wherever I have the concern, still here are the questions:

- How to hide the implementations of the IServiceBase interface from the external assemblies?
- How to restrict the construction of the SimpleService class to the Factory only so that external assembly always required to call the GetService method from the factory of generic service type?

**Some Solution (Perhaps):** Here is what I am going to do:

SimpleService will always implement the interface explicitly, something like this:

```c#
// implementation of the service
namespace SimpleFW.Services
{
    public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
    {
        public void ISimpleService.CustomMethod()
        {
            Debug.Write("CustomMethod Method Called.");
        }

        public void IServiceBase.Get()
        {
            Debug.Write("Get Method Called.");
        }

        public void IServiceBase.Create()
        {
            Debug.Write("Create Method Called.");
        }

        public void IServiceBase.Update()
        {
            Debug.Write("Update Method Called.");
        }

        public void IServiceBase.Delete()
        {
            Debug.Write("Delete Method Called.");
        }
    }
}
```

by make the changes like above will not stop the consumer of the service layer to create the instance of the SimpleService, but they will not be able to call any of the implemented methods directly. They will be only having access to the custom public methods for that service.

Answer (score 1):

> How to hide the implementations of the IServiceBase interface from the
>   external assemblies?

Use internal access [modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).

> How to restrict the construction of the SimpleService class to the
>   Factory only so that external assembly always required to call the
>   GetService method from the factory of generic service type?

Internal access modifier will solve your problem for SimpleService.

And for your factory I would suggest to used Enum to create your service.

```
    public enum ServiceType
    {
       SimpleService,
       .
       .
    }

    // For naming convention use CreateService
    IServiceBase service = ServiceFactory.GetService(ServiceType.SimpleService);


   public class ServiceFactory
   {
      public static T GetService(enum type)
      {
         // create you service here         
      }
   }
```

Comment: so what you are saying that there is no why to make it generic type class?

Comment: It is still generic you haven't seen the T after GetService.

Comment: Are you kidding me ... and how come the T is known to the class? Guess you are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

- To hide implementations of the IServiceBase you can put base interface in a separate assembly than implementation:

`assembly SimpleFW.Services.Core -> IServiceBase interface`

`assembly SimpleFW.Services.Implementation -> SimpleService class`

Be aware of that in assembly where you actually must compose your entire application, you must reference assembly with your service implementation. So the implementation of the service will be visible in that assembly. But other assemblies can use only `Services.Core` assembly and use *programing to interfaces*.

- You can restrict construction of the SimpleService class by using internal constructor.

Comment: Sorry @arkadiusz-k i am not looking for that what you are suggesting. May be i need to be more clear about the question. Let me prepare a better question and edit it here. But busy as of now will come back ...